# How to resolve diamond issue with eclipse project dependency?

Tags: java, eclipse

My java application consist of multiple modules (eclipse j2se projects) which depend on each other for class files.

The structure of project hierarchy that i require causes what is similar to diamond problem in c++ inheritance.

The module B and C inherit from A but module D needs both B and C. 
If i add the modules B and C to build path of D then D reports errors such as not being able to find the classes from A.

How do i resolve this?

Comment: Add module A to build path of D as well.

Comment: use clear dependency model using maven which takes care of transitive dependencies as well.

Comment: Eclipse has an incremental compiler. For all projects just add all other required projects to the Java build path: in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_ select _Classpath_ (or _Modulepath_ for Java 9 modules) and click _Add..._